# JavaScript user input text to options value not sending to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I want user to enter number of items from a few different textboxes in iframe and display them in parent.php as one combine options list where you can select each item and delete it if you what to. Then I want to send the final list of all options values to an email through php. I got everything working until assigning the options values to php variable. I keep getting nothing no list kin email. I'm not sure how to pass the options values to php.

This is what I got so far.

parent.php

```
<?php

 $to = 'myemail@email.com';
 $subject = 'Available Item Lists';

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      foreach ($_POST['qlist'] as $selectList)   {
           echo "You have the following :" .$selectList; // Display all 
   selection values
      $body = $selectList;
      }

      $headers = '$email';
      $headers .=  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

      mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
  }
  ?>

    <form method="post" id="quote-form" name="quote-form" action="?"> 
        <label for="items">List of items</label><br />
        <div class="form-section">
            <select name="qlist[]" id="qlist" multiple="multiple"></select>
            <button id="deleteButton" onclick="deleteEntry(); return 
false;">Delete</button>
       <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit">
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

       function displayQuantity(noOfitems, labelVal)  {
          var qq = noOfitems;
          var labelName = labelVal;
          var quoteQuantity = document.getElementById("qlist");
          var quantity = quoteQuantity.value;
          quantity += labelName + ": ";
          quantity += qq;
          quantity += " pcs\n";
          quoteQuantity.value = quantity;
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = quantity;
          quoteQuantity.add(option);

       }

       function deleteEntry() {
          var myList = document.getElementById('qlist');
          var i;
          for (i = myList.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
              if (myList.options[i].selected) {
                  myList.remove(i);
              }
          }
       }
</script>
```

iframe.php

```
<div class="order-quantity">
   <form name="form">
        <label id="itemType">Heavy Duty Square Core Drilled</label>
        <input type="number" id="total-quantity" name="quantity" />
        <button type="button" id="addItem"  
             onclick="parent.displayQuantity(this.form.quantity.value, 
         getVal())">Add</button>
   </form>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getVal() {
       var labelVal = document.getElementById("itemType").textContent;
       return labelVal;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Why iFrame? It has to be from same origin anyway so why not just a div?

Comment: Also NEVER do this: `name="submit" id="submit"` it will hide the form's submit event if you ever want to use it

Comment: Ok. I'll change it. Submit button still works though.

Comment: No console errors. I need to load other pages within the iframe so that the parent page stays without reloading. This is not an issue. I got it working. The problem is php is not getting the options list values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!! I added this function to the submit button to select all options in a list :D

```
   function selectAll()  { 
       selectBox = document.getElementById("qlist");
       for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) { 
           selectBox.options[i].selected = true; 
       } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

From

```
 foreach ($_POST['qlist'] as $selectList)   {
           echo "You have the following :" .$selectList; // Display all 
   selection values
      $body = $selectList;
      }
```

to

```
$Data = $_POST["qlist"];
      foreach ($Data as $selectList)   {
           echo "You have the following :" .$selectList; // Display all 
      $body = $selectList;
      }
```

Comment: Is it because php is getting empty qlist[] options and not recognising the user's input?

Comment: in your qustion you mentioned that file name as parent.html
if you use .html  File php functions will not work you need to change it to .php or you can create new php function and give form action to new custom created function

Comment: Mistyped. I meant parent.php. All files are saved in .php.

Comment: Actually this code is working on my local server .
if you using lampp server please check any error logs are there using 
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: I'm running it on both local and on my domain server. I'm still unable to get qlist values from php on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check "enable_post_data_reading" status

> Disabling this option causes $_POST and $_FILES not to be populated.

if it disabled in your php.ini file then please enable it and restart the apache

Comment: I'm able to pass other attributes such as user name, email address, comment through php that sent to an email. Just this option values having problem passing to php :(

Comment: Baisically this code is working in my system , i add 4-5 options the mutli select and select some of them and i get the selected values in my POST array

Comment: Yeh the thing is I can't add the options. The user have to add them. And once the user finished adding them the user then click on send button to send off to an email his option list.

Comment: One qus, after adding the options to the multi select option, did you select  any of the options before click send button
please confirm that the you folow the given steps
1)add options to multi select
2)Select Any added options from multi selected options
3)click send button

Comment: I want to send all the options in the list to php. I have done the first and third steps. I'm not sure how to send all the options without selecting them.

Comment: I got it. I just add this function and called this method to the submit button. :))                                                                                                
                 function selectAll() { 
    
               selectBox = document.getElementById("qlist");

               for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++)  { 
                    selectBox.options[i].selected = true; 
               } 
       }